# How to test Apache Airflow tasks that uses XCom

Tags: python, testing, airflow

I'm trying to figure out a way to test a DAG where I have a couple of tasks communicating using XCom.

Since the console command only allow me to run tasks from a DAG, is there a way to test the communication without having to run the DAG via the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way that worked for me.

Even though the Airflow web page states that the test command does not generate or keeps any state, running the airflow test command in sequence worked.

Basically you do:

```
Airflow test my_dag task1 date
Airflow test my_dag task2 date
```

where task1 returns the value or uses xcom_push method to send the value and then task2 run xcom_pull to get the value and move on.

It worked for me. Please comment if you have different approaches or other questions.

Comment: To explain further why this method works, airflow uses pickle to serialize the values in an xcom and store them in the database. When you run `airflow test` without the `--dry_run` flag, it still persists some information for that run of the program into the database, including the xcom for `task1`. This is problematic if you desire your database to not contain a lot of test runs. Unfortunately for us, airflow doesn't really have a good way to mock xcom at time of writing, so this (or rewriting your operator to not use xcom during testing) are your options.