# airflow test mode xcom pull/push not working

Tags: testing, airflow

I try to test 2 tasks through the airflow cli `test` command`

The first task run, auto pushes last console out to xcom and i see the value `some value` in the airflow GUI as expected

When i run the second task via airflow cli test command i just get None as return value but as i have read here: [How to test Apache Airflow tasks that uses XCom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475042/how-to-test-apache-airflow-tasks-that-uses-xcom) that it should work and at least the xcom_push is obvious working, why not the xcom_pull?

Someone has a hint how to get this working?
Provide context is set to true.

Example code:

```py
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    bash_command='echo "some value"',
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='t2',
    bash_command='echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="t1") }}',
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Thanks!

Edit: when i run the code (DAG) without test mode the xcom_pull works fine

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "test" runs without saving anything to the metadata database which is why when you run the puller task, you get "None" as a result and when you actually run the DAG code, it works.

You can query the metadata database directly after testing the first task to verify this.

Comment: Well thats kind of the problem. I would understand when testmode never writes in the metadata database or would always write. But in my case it writes in the metadata database but a subsequent can not read the written value from the metadata database which is a little bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Context seems to be missing here, along with xcom_push=True, we need to use  provide_context=True